# Session is null on ipad

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ipad

I have the following code in action:

```
public JsonResult AddTicketToCart(...)
{
   ... 
   Session.Add("Cart", cart);
   return Json(new { IsSuccess = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In the JS code:

```
$.get('/desk/AddTicketToCart', { clientId: clientId, sessionId: sessionId, levelId: levelId, places: places, isWithoutPlace: isWithoutPlace, delivery: delivery }, function (data) {
     if (data.IsSuccess) {
          if (isQuickBuy)
              window.location = '/desk/paywizard';
          else
              window.location = $('#wiz_header .first-child>a').attr('href');
      } else {
                 toastr.options.timeOut = 10000;
                 toastr.error('Error.');
                }
            });
```

This `PayWizard` action contain:

```
if (Session["Cart"] == null)
return new HttpNotFoundResult();

var model = CreateViewData<PersonalInfoViewData>();
return View("PersonalInformation", model);
```

The problem in that I get 404 error on Ipad. On desktop all works fine. I add logging messages to `AddTicketToCart`:

```
public JsonResult AddTicketToCart(...)
    {
       ... 
       Session.Add("Cart", cart);

       if(Session["Cart"] != null)
            Logging.Log.Info("Cart not null");
       else
            Logging.Log.Info("Cart equal null");

        var test = (CartModel) Session["Cart"];
        if( test != null)
        {
            Logging.Log.Info("CartModel not null");
            Logging.Log.Info("Tickets count: {0}", test.Tickets.Count);
        }
        else
            Logging.Log.Info("CartModel equal null");

       return Json(new { IsSuccess = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The output is the following:

```
2012-11-02 09:37:34.4887 | Info | Cart not null 

2012-11-02 09:37:34.4887 | Info | CartModel not null 

2012-11-02 09:37:34.4887 | Info | Tickets count: 1
```

As you can see the `Cart` in session is exist. Butin `Paywizard` is equal null. 
Where is a problem?

Comment: is this happens only on safari? try other browsers on ipad, does they work fine?

Comment: @EdiWang: only on Safari and desktop Safari too

Comment: check this http://forums.asp.net/t/1212709.aspx/1

Comment: @EdiWang: I have enable cookies and works. Thanks.